# Can a Service Worker activate an Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, service-worker, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

My initial problem was that Outlook add-ins couldn't run code in the background, since it is only event based activated (user interaction).

I needed to do some processing to the email body before sending it, but the process can be quite long to execute and I didn't want the user to be blocked on the compose page waiting for the message to be sent.

So I created a service worker that does exactly that, it run and process the email body, but now I can't find a way to send the processed email...

This was the code for sending the email, but since I'm in a service worker I can't use Office.js anymore:

```
//Soap request
const request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' +
    '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendOnly">' +
    '      <m:Items>' +
    '        <t:Message>' +
    '          <t:Subject>' + subject + '</t:Subject>' +
    '             <t:Body BodyType="HTML"><![CDATA[' + htmlBody + ']]></t:Body>' +
    '          <t:ToRecipients>' +
    '            <t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>' + recipient + '</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>' +
    '          </t:ToRecipients>' +
    '        </t:Message>' +
    '      </m:Items>' +
    '    </m:CreateItem>' +
    '  </soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';

//Send request to echange servers
Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, (asyncResult) => {
    if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
        console.error("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Message sent!");
        mailboxItem.close();
    }
});
```

Since the mailbox is closed in the outlook web page, I can't send back the processed email body back to my add-in and send it, I need to activate it with a user interaction.

My questions are the following:
Is there a way to activate my add-in via my service worker to then make a new EWS request? Or is there a way to use the Microsoft graph API to send my email? (I'm not sure if it can work since I need to send emails on behalf of a user, through my service worker)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the scenario you mentioned is not supported. Once the send is clicked, and the draft is closed, the email is sent. The supported scenario is that you can block the email from sending and do the processing and once processing is done email will be sent.